# Correctly storing Google OAuth access token

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth, access-token, google-api-php-client

I am about to start using **Google's Calendar API** where I am asking an access to my user's calendar. In the [php docs example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php#step_2_set_up_the_sample) the token is being stored in a file (token.json), but in my case each user can have an access token, so I am thinking to store it in user's database table.

- Is it safe storing it in database?
- Do I need to encrypt it before storing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Access tokens expire in an hour. There is no reason to store the access token in your database.  What you should be storing is your refresh token. The refresh token can be used by your application to request a new access token as it needs.

Recommend storing the contents of token.json as its easer to feed the php client library that object.  By replacing `file_get_contents($tokenPath)` with something like reading from your database.

- Is it safe storing it in database?

Storing tokens in the database is standard prosedure. It should be safe. Anyone that hacks your database would need your client id and client secret to request a new access token using the refresh tokens stored there.

- Do I need to encrypt it before storing?

You can but TBH I don't bother.

Comment: Very informative answer, that cleared many of my questions, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

What I do is save it in the database and use the endpoint [https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=${your_token}](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=$%7Byour_token%7D) to validate if the token I have in the database is still alive, if I don't get another token with the following endpoint [https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&refresh_token=${REFRESH_TOKEN}&grant_type=refresh_token](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?client_id=$%7BCLIENT_ID%7D&client_secret=$%7BCLIENT_SECRET%7D&refresh_token=$%7BREFRESH_TOKEN%7D&grant_type=refresh_token), with this I keep the live token as much as possible.